# how to stop 360 rotation .js on last frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using http://nick-jonas.github.io/threesixtyjs/ that code to animate a click-and-drag image sequence, but I would like to have it stop on the first and last frame, instead of continuing in a loop. I've taken a look at it but the script is way over my head, and I'm not sure how to do it most effectively.

here is the HTML, followed by the javascript. any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>ThreeSixty</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-device-width:800px)"  href="css/mobile.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-device-width:801px)" href="css/css.css">



</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
<h1>HELLO SHIR</h1>
<h2>I'm Sean Connery</h2>
    <div class="threesixty-wrapper">

        <div class="threesixty" data-path="img/src1/edison{index}.jpg" data-count="50">

        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script src="js/jquery.threesixty.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var $threeSixty = $('.threesixty');

            $threeSixty.threeSixty({
                dragDirection: 'horizontal',
                useKeys: true,
                draggable: true
            });

            $('.next').click(function(){
                $threeSixty.nextFrame();
            });

            $('.prev').click(function(){
                $threeSixty.prevFrame();
            });

            $threeSixty.on('down', function(){
                $('.ui, h1, h2, .label, .examples').stop().animate({opacity:0}, 300);
            });

            $threeSixty.on('up', function(){
                $('.ui, h1, h2, .label, .examples').stop().animate({opacity:1}, 500);
            });
        });
    </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>



/*!
 * ThreeSixty: A jQuery plugin for generating a draggable 360 preview from an image sequence.
 * Version: 0.1.2
 * Original author: @nick-jonas
 * Website: http://www.workofjonas.com
 * Licensed under the MIT license
 */

;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {


var scope,
pluginName = 'threeSixty',
defaults = {
    dragDirection: 'horizontal',
    useKeys: false,
    draggable: true
},
dragDirections = ['horizontal', 'vertical'],
options = {},
$el = {},
data = [],
total = 0,
loaded = 0;

/**
 * Constructor
 * @param {jQuery Object} element       main jQuery object
 * @param {Object} customOptions        options to override defaults
 */
function ThreeSixty( element, customOptions ) {
    scope = this;
    this.element = element;
    options = options = $.extend( {}, defaults, customOptions) ;
    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;

    // make sure string input for drag direction is valid
    if($.inArray(options.dragDirection, dragDirections) < 0){
        options.dragDirection = defaults.dragDirection;
    }

    this.init();
}

// PUBLIC API -----------------------------------------------------

$.fn.destroy = ThreeSixty.prototype.destroy = function(){
    if(options.useKeys === true) $(document).unbind('keydown', this.onKeyDown);
    $(this).removeData();
    $el.html('');
};

$.fn.nextFrame = ThreeSixty.prototype.nextFrame = function(){
    $(this).each(function(i){
        var $this = $(this),
            val = $this.data('lastVal') || 0,
            thisTotal = $this.data('count');

        val = val + 1;

        $this.data('lastVal', val);

        if(val >= thisTotal) val = val % (thisTotal - 1);
        else if(val <= -thisTotal) val = val % (thisTotal - 1);
        if(val > 0) val = thisTotal - val;

        val = Math.abs(val);

        $this.find('.threesixty-frame').css({display: 'none'});
        $this.find('.threesixty-frame:eq(' + val + ')').css({display: 'block'});
    });
};

$.fn.prevFrame = ThreeSixty.prototype.prevFrame = function(){
    $(this).each(function(i){
        var $this = $(this),
            val = $this.data('lastVal') || 0,
            thisTotal = $this.data('count');

        val = val - 1;

        $this.data('lastVal', val);

        if(val >= thisTotal) val = val % (thisTotal - 1);
        else if(val <= -thisTotal) val = val % (thisTotal - 1);
        if(val > 0) val = thisTotal - val;

        val = Math.abs(val);

        $this.find('.threesixty-frame').css({display: 'none'});
        $this.find('.threesixty-frame:eq(' + val + ')').css({display: 'block'});
    });
};



// PRIVATE METHODS -------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Initializiation, called once from constructor
 * @return null
 */
ThreeSixty.prototype.init = function () {
    var $this = $(this.element);

    // setup main container
    $el = $this;

    // store data attributes for each 360
    $this.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            path = $this.data('path'),
            count = $this.data('count');
        data.push({'path': path, 'count': count, 'loaded': 0, '$el': $this});
        total += count;
    });

    _disableTextSelectAndDragIE8();

    this.initLoad();
};

/**
 * Start loading all images
 * @return null
 */
ThreeSixty.prototype.initLoad = function() {
    var i = 0, len = data.length, url, j;
    $el.addClass('preloading');
    for(i; i < len; i++){
        j = 0;
        for(j; j < data[i].count; j++){
            url = data[i].path.replace('{index}', j);
            $('<img/>').data('index', i).attr('src', url).load(this.onLoadComplete);
        }
    }
};

ThreeSixty.prototype.onLoadComplete = function(e) {
    var index = $(e.currentTarget).data('index'),
        thisObj = data[index];
    thisObj.loaded++;
    if(thisObj.loaded === thisObj.count){
        scope.onLoadAllComplete(index);
    }
};

ThreeSixty.prototype.onLoadAllComplete = function(objIndex) {
    var $this = data[objIndex].$el,
        html = '',
        l = data[objIndex].count,
        pathTemplate = data[objIndex].path,
        i = 0;

    // remove preloader
    $this.html('');
    $this.removeClass('preloading');

    // add 360 images
    for(i; i < l; i++){
        var display = (i === 0) ? 'block' : 'none';
        html += '<img class="threesixty-frame" style="display:' + display + ';" data-index="' + i + '" src="' + pathTemplate.replace('{index}', i) + '"/>';
    }
    $this.html(html);

    this.attachHandlers(objIndex);
};

var startY = 0,
    thisTotal = 0,
    $downElem = null,
    lastY = 0,
    lastX = 0,
    lastVal = 0,
    isMouseDown = false;
ThreeSixty.prototype.attachHandlers = function(objIndex) {
    var that = this;
    var $this = data[objIndex].$el;

    // add draggable events
    if(options.draggable){
        // if touch events supported, use
        if(typeof document.ontouchstart !== 'undefined' &&
            typeof document.ontouchmove !== 'undefined' &&
            typeof document.ontouchend !== 'undefined' &&
            typeof document.ontouchcancel !== 'undefined'){
            var elem = $this.get()[0];
            elem.addEventListener('touchstart', that.onTouchStart);
            elem.addEventListener('touchmove', that.onTouchMove);
            elem.addEventListener('touchend', that.onTouchEnd);
            elem.addEventListener('touchcancel', that.onTouchEnd);
        }
    }

    // mouse down
    $this.mousedown(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        thisTotal = $(this).data('count');
        $downElem = $(this);
        startY = e.screenY;
        lastVal = $downElem.data('lastVal') || 0;
        lastX = $downElem.data('lastX') || 0;
        lastY = $downElem.data('lastY') || 0;
        isMouseDown = true;
        $downElem.trigger('down');
    });

    // arrow keys
    if(options.useKeys === true){
        $(document).bind('keydown', that.onKeyDown);
    }

    // mouse up
    $(document, 'html', 'body').mouseup(that.onMouseUp);
    $(document).blur(that.onMouseUp);
    $('body').mousemove(function(e){
        that.onMove(e.screenX, e.screenY);
    });
};

ThreeSixty.prototype.onTouchStart = function(e) {
    var touch = e.touches[0];
    e.preventDefault();
    $downElem = $(e.target).parent();
    thisTotal = $downElem.data('count');
    startX = touch.pageX;
    startY = touch.pageY;
    lastVal = $downElem.data('lastVal') || 0;
    lastX = $downElem.data('lastX') || 0;
    lastY = $downElem.data('lastY') || 0;
    isMouseDown = true;
    $downElem.trigger('down');
};

ThreeSixty.prototype.onTouchMove = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var touch = e.touches[0];
    scope.onMove(touch.pageX, touch.pageY);
};

ThreeSixty.prototype.onTouchEnd = function(e) {

};

ThreeSixty.prototype.onMove = function(screenX, screenY){
    if(isMouseDown){
        var x = screenX,
            y = screenY,
            val = 0;

        $downElem.trigger('move');

        if(options.dragDirection === 'vertical'){
            if(y > lastY){
                val = lastVal - 1;
            }else{
                val = lastVal + 1;
            }
        }else{
            if(x > lastX){
                val = lastVal - 1;
            }else if(x === lastX){
                return;
            }else{
                val = lastVal + 1;
            }
        }

        lastVal = val;
        lastY = y;
        lastX = x;

        $downElem.data('lastY', lastY);
        $downElem.data('lastX', lastX);
        $downElem.data('lastVal', lastVal);

        if(val >= thisTotal) val = val % (thisTotal - 1);
        else if(val <= -thisTotal) val = val % (thisTotal - 1);
        if(val > 0) val = thisTotal - val;

        val = Math.abs(val);

        $downElem.find('.threesixty-frame').css({display: 'none'});
        $downElem.find('.threesixty-frame:eq(' + val + ')').css({display: 'block'});
    }
};

ThreeSixty.prototype.onKeyDown = function(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode){
        case 37: // left
            $el.prevFrame();
            break;
        case 39: // right
            $el.nextFrame();
            break;
    }
};

ThreeSixty.prototype.onMouseUp = function(e) {
    isMouseDown = false;
    $downElem.trigger('up');
};

/**
 * Disables text selection and dragging on IE8 and below.
 */
var _disableTextSelectAndDragIE8 = function() {
  // Disable text selection.
  document.body.onselectstart = function() {
      return false;
  };

  // Disable dragging.
  document.body.ondragstart = function() {
      return false;
  };
};


/**
 * A really lightweight plugin wrapper around the constructor,
    preventing against multiple instantiations
 * @param  {Object} options
 * @return {jQuery Object}
 */
$.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
    return this.each(function () {
        if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
            $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName,
            new ThreeSixty( this, options ));
        }
    });
};

})( jQuery, window, document );
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help yoyu on your way

The code you'll need to look at is in $.fn.prevFrame and $.fn.nextFrame:

```
if(val >= thisTotal) val = val % (thisTotal - 1);
else if(val <= -thisTotal) val = val % (thisTotal - 1);
```

These loop the variable `val` with the modulus sign. You should be able to stop this by setting them to `thisTotal` like so:

```
if(val >= thisTotal) val = thisTotal - 1;
else if(val <= -thisTotal) val = thisTotal - 1;
```

Good luck.